# How to make async code run on startup - Python

Tags: python, asynchronous

Heyy,
how would I make my `async`hronous code run on startup?

So this is the easiest example I could think of to make.

```py
async def mainMenuCLI():
  print("This is the CLI")
```

And I want the asynchronous `mainMenuCLI` to run on startup but I don't want it to take as many tasks because I'm not sure what is the max :(

I need it to be async because of `async_input`, discord.py and stuff, just don't tell me to make it sync, thanks!

Comment: By 'startup' you mean the machine startup? In this case, the OS will be relevant. Besides, what have you tried with this minimal example of yours? Why doesn't it work? It is nice to show effort on the solution before asking here. Please, read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: By startup I mean script startup, it doesn't work because I can't await outside of a function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question... Do you need something likethis?

```py
import asyncio


async def async_example():
    print("hellooooo, I'm an async function")
 


async def main():
    asyncio.Task(async_example())  


if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

You can add some tasks outside the async func if you need:

```py
import asyncio


async def async_example():
    print("hellooooo, I'm an async function")
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    print("async function done")


async def main():
    asyncio.Task(async_example())  

    print('This is before wait')
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    print('This is after await')
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    print('Ok, goodbye')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

*Note: if your py version is prior to 3.7, [change asyncio.Task per asyncio.ensure_future](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.create_task).

Comment: Yes! Thanks alot! Marked as helpful